# libspatialite build errors on linux

Tags: linux, build, compiler-errors

I am trying to build the libspatialite for Android.The source is from https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index available through libspatialite-4.4.0-RC0.tar.gz.All dependencies like PROJ,GEOS,SQLite3 are installed successfully on linux.The build stops right after the command

```
./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-eabi
Errors

checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2 in -lsqlite3... no
configure: error: 'libsqlite3' is required but it doesn't seem to be installed on this system
However, I can see the libsqlite3 in libs directory.

[root@euro libspatialite-4.4.0-RC1]# locate libsqlite3
/home/gis/Desktop/Softwares/FWTools-linux-x86_64-3.0.6/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
/home/gis/Desktop/Softwares/FWTools-linux-x86_64-3.0.6/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/home/gis/spatialdb/libspatialite-4.4.0-RC1/libsqlite3.la
/home/gis/spatialdb/sqlite-autoconf-3140000/libsqlite3.la
/home/gis/spatialdb/sqlite-autoconf-3140000/.libs/libsqlite3.a
/home/gis/spatialdb/sqlite-autoconf-3140000/.libs/libsqlite3.la
/home/gis/spatialdb/sqlite-autoconf-3140000/.libs/libsqlite3.lai
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.la
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la
[root@euro libspatialite-4.4.0-RC1]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on mentioned error it seems that compiler is unable to resolve dependecy. Try to export environment variable like this and  re configure.

```
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-eabi"
export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ar
export AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}-as
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ld
export RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ranlib
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}-nm
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/ak/<lib_1>/lib -L/home/ak/<lib_2>/lib"
export LIBS="-l1 -l2"
```

I was also facing issues while compiling `curl` code.By Providing these details I was able to build successfully.